# Presentación modal Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c

Tengo un viewcontroller, el cual tiene un textview que al hacer click abre un segundo viewcontroller de manera modal para simular un AlertController personalizado, en este controller tengo varias textviews y un botón.
El botón lo que hace es concatenar los strings y escribirlo sobre el textField del primer viewController. Este es el codigo

**ViewController.m**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(popUpDetails:)];
[cellTextView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

-(void)popUpDetails:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        PackagePopUpVC* detailsPopUp = [[PackagePopUpVC alloc]initWithNibName:@"PackagePopUpVC" bundle:nil];
        [detailsPopUp setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext];
        [self presentViewController:detailsPopUp animated:NO completion:nil];
    });
    [self llenarInfo];
}

-(void)llenarInfo{
    NSLog(@"%@",descripcionPaquete);
    self.courierModelClassObj.strNote = descripcionPaquete;
    descriptionTextView.text = self.courierModelClassObj.strNote;
}
```

**PackagePopUpVC.m**

```
- (IBAction)btnOk_onClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *mensaje = @"";
    //concatenacion
    descripcionPaquete = mensaje;
    CRCourierUpdateViewController *vc = [[CRCourierUpdateViewController alloc]init];
    vc.descriptionTextView.text = mensaje;
    //vc.mensajeroObj.strNote = mensaje;
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

La variable **descripcionPaquete** es una global. El objetivo de copiar datos entre controllers esta bien, el problema es que debo repetir el proceso dos veces para que funcione, es decir tengo que abrir dos veces el popUp para que se copie los datos.

Alguna idea del error. muchas gracias

Comment: porque haces la presentación de la modal dentro de un dispatch? no es necesario. Ademas después de hacer el dispatch, se ejecuta el llenarInfo. Lo mismo todavía se esta creando el controlador mientras se termina de ejecutar el llenarInfo

Comment: desde donde llamarías entonces el método llenarInfo?

Comment: para pasar datos del packagepopupvc al viewcontroller haría un protocolo o un delegado o pondría el delegado del textfield a viewcontroller

Comment: El paso de datos lo tengo controlado, el problema es mostrar es dato que paso desde el popUp en un textView del viewController al cerrar el popUp.

Comment: pues una vez que recibas ese dato se lo asignas al testField.text = xxxx o en el viewWillAppear del viewcontroller se lo pones ahí, que cuando se cierre el popup se ejecutara ese método

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar delegados para transferir parametros entre clases,

Enlace:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html